# zsh: command not found: symfony on ubuntu 20

Tags: bash, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have installed zsh shell for my computer , and when i want to run some command , example : symfony server:start , i get this error => zsh: command not found: symfony

i can solve the problem temporary on the current shell session by taping this : export PATH="$HOME/.symfony/bin:$PATH" , but when i close the shell and reopen it , i should run for the second time this : export PATH="$HOME/.symfony/bin:$PATH"

```
PATH="$HOME/.symfony/bin:$PATH"
```

Any help to apply it permanently ?

Comment: As an aside, your question can't be about [tag:bash] and [tag:zsh] at the same time; clearly, the Bash tag should be removed (but moot now for this question).

Comment: If you want certain settings to apply on every new `zsh` you start, put them in an appropriate startup file. Since there are various startup files considered, depending of the kind of zsh which you are starting, study the section names _STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES_ in the _zshall_ man-page, to ensure that you place them in the right file.

Comment: thank you all for this help , i have resolve this by adding this line PATH="$HOME/.symfony/bin:$PATH" to .zshrc file